# Перемещение объекта мышью three.js

Tags: webgl, three.js

Как осуществить следующую задачу:
нужно перемещать объект мышью по выбранной плоскости или оси

В [этом](http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_transform) примере есть все, что нужно, но там довольно много кода и копание в нем займет кучу времени, не факт что успешно.

Конкретно интересует следующее:
как определить новую позицию объекта по плоскости, например, XZ, если известна точка пересечения брошенного луча на объект, позиция объекта, и после направление луча от камеры

Пока мысль об одном: найти пересечение луча с мнимой плоскостью XZ (и как это будет выглядеть практически) и к соответствующим координатам позиции объекта добавить разницу точек пересечения первого луча и второго?

Comment: @Ni55aN, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: var direction = new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0);
    var speed = 1;
    var vector = direction.multiplyScalar( speed, speed, speed );         
    object.position.x += vector.x;
    object.position.y += vector.y;
    object.position.z += vector.z;  перемещение вдоль оси, определяется вектором направления

Answer (score 1):

Если хочется легко и быстро сделать перемещение объектов мышкой вдоль заданной плоскости, можно использовать класс EventsControls. Пример [тут](http://alexan0308.github.io/threejs/examples/#misc_controls_events).

Код выглядит довольно просто:

```
<script src="js/controls/EventsControls.js"></script>

EventsControls = new EventsControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( mesh );

EventsControls.attach( mesh );

//

function render() {
       EventsControls.update();
       controls.update();
       renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Comment: спасибо, попробую))